# add a class to one particular li element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list which is dynamically created, and I need to add a class called 'selected' to one particular -li-.

The -ul- is a list of the Days of the Week, and the -li- that needs to be selected is the current day. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to add this class to just the one element, and the entire list disappears whenever I try to add this class. Here's my code:

```
var weekday = new Array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");
var today = day.getDay();
for(var x=0;x<=6;x++){
    $('ul').append(
        $('<li>')
        .toggleClass(function(){
            if(today == x){ return 'selected'; }
            else{ return ''; };
        });
        .append( $('<a href = "#' + weekday[x].toLowerCase() + '">' + weekday[x] + '</a>'));    
    );      
$('li:last').addClass('last-child');
```

Can someone help me figure out how to add this class to just the current day's -li-?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the advice from the other comments and fixing some errors fixed the code:

```
var weekday = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'],
    today = new Date().getDay(),
    list = $('ul');

for(var x=0;x<=6;x++){
    list.append(
        $('<li></li>', {
            html : '<a href = "#' + weekday[x].toLowerCase() + '">' + weekday[x] + '</a>'
        }).toggleClass(function(){
            if(today == x){
                return 'selected';
            }
        }).bind('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().children('li').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        })
    );
}

$('li:last').addClass('last-child');
```

Comment: This adds the 'selected' class to the correct li element when the page loads, but it doesn't change at all when the user clicks on a different link

Comment: I added a click event handler to change the class when a user clicks on the links.

Comment: this does what I'm looking for in my question, but what I didn't realize when asking my question is this, so maybe you can help me, if not I'm still working towards it myself...  I'm using yahoo tabview, and this unordered list is the yui-nav (the tabs). the content areas that go with each tab all have the class 'content'. Basically, each content area should only show when the corresponding li has been selected. the answer above that has the jQuery.map deals with this, but does not select the li that matches today. this code does that, but all the content areas show all the time. any ideas?

Comment: P.S. I have PHP that does everything that I need if that might help. I need to do all this to convert all my PHP to javascript so that I can send a mobile website through phonegap to create an app

Comment: I'm not familiar with yahoo tabview. Can you give each of the content areas an id? Like id="mon", id="tue, etc. If so, you can just add some code that hides all other content areas and shows the one you want.

Comment: I can do that, sure. Then I wouldn't even need yahoo tabview. Where would I add the code to hide and show the related div's, in the .bind() function? and should I use .hide() and .show?

Comment: that almost got it, but I did some editing and got it working great!

Answer (score 4):

```
if(today = x)
```

- = assign
- == compares

Another way of doing it:

```
var weekday = new Array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");
var lis = [];
var today = new Date().getDay();
jQuery.map( weekday, 
    function( day, ind ){
        var cls = ind===today ? " class='selected'" : "";
        lis.push( "<li><a" + cls +" href='#" + day.toLowerCase() + "'>"+ day + "</a></li>" );
    }
);
$("ul").html( lis.join("") );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This gives me a 'selected' class for the link the user clicks on, but I also need it to add the selected class to the li element that contains 'today', and it isn't doing that, and I don't even know where to start editing all of this - I'm gonna have to look up a reference on 1/2 this stuff just to understand whats going one. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Is day defined as new Date?

var day = new Date();

or var today = new Date().getDay();

Comment: I have var today = new Day.getDay(); and I added var day = new Date(); but there's no difference in the results

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
var weekday = new Array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");
var d = new Date(); 
var today = d.getDay(); 

for(var x=0;x<=6;x++){     
    $('ul').append(         
        $('<li><a href = "#' + weekday[x].toLowerCase() + '">' + weekday[x] + '</a>')
    );      

    $('li:last-child').addClass('last-child');

    if(x == today)
    {   
        $('li:gt('+(x - 1)+')').toggleClass('selected');
    }
}
```

Comment: This renders the same results as the answer above it. It's becoming apparent to me that my original code was far-fetched from anything that will bring the specific results I'm looking for